# Iterating Over Array - Only Modifying Integers Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops

I am trying to iterate over an array that contains both numbers and strings. Right now I am using the following code to accomplish this:

```
def mod_method(source_array, integer_increase)
source_array.map! do |x|
    if x.is_a? Fixnum
        x+=integer_increase
    else
        x
     end 
end
p source
end
```

So this will iterate over all the integers and add the second parameter (an integer) to all the values. What I don't understand is that is I do this instead:

```
def mod_method(source_array, integer_increase)
source_array.map! do |x|
    if x.is_a? Fixnum
        x+=integer_increase
     end 
end
p source
end
```

It will return everything that is not an integer as NIL. All I did was get rid of the 'else x'. Wouldn't it just skip over the elements that are not of type Fixnum? Why would it set those values to nil? I think if I can figure that out I will be able to refactor the code to make is look better. Thank you.

Comment: `map!` replaces each value in the array with the return value of the specified block. discarding the `else`, returns `nil` for non-integer elements

Comment: You need to supply sample input data, and show an example of your desired output.

Comment: Using the `else` is entirely acceptable. `map` needs to see something returned through each iteration of the block, otherwise it uses `nil`, AKA "I got nothing".

Answer (score 0):

Because you're returning nil when it's not a number.

What you can do is call `compact` method after the iteration and it will get rid of nil values.

Like this:

```
def mod_method(source_array, integer_increase)
  source_array.map! do |x|
    if x.is_a? Fixnum
      x+=integer_increase
    end
  end.compact!
  p source
end
```

Comment: You're not returning nothing, you're returning `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
def mod_method(ary, offset)
  ary.map{ |x| 
    (Fixnum === x) ? x += offset : x
  }
end

mod_method([1, 'a'], 1) # => [2, "a"]
```

That doesn't modify the passed-in array, it returns a new one. You already know to use `map!` if you want to mangle the array passed in.

`Fixnum === x` is a simple way of asking Fixnum if x is of its type:

```
Fixnum === 1 # => true
Fixnum === 'a' # => false
```

The rest of it is a ternary statement which is a single-line version of an `if`/`then`/`else`.

Comment: thanks man i really like this! I was trying to find a way to make it look less chunky and this appears to be it.

Comment: It's basically what your `if`-based logic does, however, the `?:` ternary does help make that clearer, sometimes. It can cause code to become less readable if misused, so in general it's recommended that it be used for only single-line situations, like this one.